# Having issue in installing mongoDB PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I am very new to mongoDB. I have downloaded the setup for mongoDB but before that I have to install the mongoDB PHP driver.

When I downloaded the driver I got these instruction in the documentation:

> Installation
>
> To install:
>
> $ phpize
> $ ./configure
> $ make
> $ sudo make install

When I run this command `phpize` on `cmd` then it gives me this error

> 'phpize' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I am using:

- MongoDB version 1.0
- PHP version 5.5
- Windows 7

Comment: Well it basically means that you don't have your development enviroment set up to compile php extensions. I'm guessing the `$` for command prompt means a *nix variant? Possibly linux? Most packages would be set up with `php-dev` for most distributions, and probably a few more dependencies ( c compiler, etc ). Search for `"compiling php extensions linux"`

Comment: so what's your suggestion ? I am using windows 7

Comment: How about what the offcial documentation says? [Installing a PHP extension on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link i have read the document compeltely, the problem is  i am unable to locate the `.dll` from the package of mongodb php driver. which i found on this link `http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows`. There are some c/c++ files included in the package, I don't know that i have to compile the files which are included in package? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue a week ago. I struggled a lot and finally found that I had downloaded the wrong DLL file. (My system is 64-bit, so I downloaded the DLL for 64-bit. However, phpInfo() shows that my php is 32-bit. So, I downloaded the 32-bit DLL file and it worked!)

Have a look at the following tutorial if you still have any queries:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBKNKl5OG_8&t=356s

I hope that helps!